# GLUT Window not refreshing after window overlap

Tags: c, linux, opengl, x11, glut

I am developing an application with GLUT in C.
I have a basic GLUT canvas where I draw OpenGL stuff.

I have a problem when other X11 windows are overlapping the GLUT canvas and then removed. The GLUT canvas is polluted with the content of the overlapping windows, and there is not refreshing.

How can I manage to refresh the GLUT canvas, when the transcient windows are removed ? Shall I use a system call or something like that to detect this situation, so that I could trigger a **glutSwapBuffers()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a display callback and do all the drawing from there. GLUT will call the display callback whenever a window requires refreshing. Actually you should not draw from anywhere else but the display callback.

Comment: Thank you datenwolf for your answer, I was not drawing the things inside the display callback, that's why I had this issue.